# jQuery scrollTop doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chat-based system I'm building in an MVC framework using jQuery/AJAX. When the page loads, it fills the chat window with the last x responses from the database.

I've looked everywhere for an answer, and can't find anything on this. Every alternative I've tried doesn't resolve it.

I use this function to scroll down to the bottom of my chat window;

```
function scrollToBottom()
{
    var panel = $('.panel-body#main-window');
    panel.scrollTop(panel.height());
}
```

This is my CSS:

```
.panel-body#main-window
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%
}
```

This works fine when I bind it to an onClick handler function, but no matter what I've tried, it won't scroll to the bottom of my panel before the end of my `$(document).ready();` call. So when the page is loaded, it doesn't scroll to the bottom of my container.

Tried this both in Firefox and Chrome and neither work. My function is being called, but when it's called inside `$(document).ready();`, it refuses to scroll to the bottom of my panel.

I also tried this function, which doesn't work either;

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    setTimeout(scrollToBottom(), 500);

});
```

Comment: Is the panel visible at the moment you try to scroll? If not, the `.height()` will return `0`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK; no, that's not the issue. I used console.log to return the height, and it's returning the correct value. Even tried manually setting my own. The function is returning the DOM object and the correct height. It's just not working on page load.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code posted here (other than the setTimeout usage already pointed out in the answer below): eg. http://jsfiddle.net/znxca14s/ Could you make a reproducible sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not passing a reference of the function to your setTimeout, should be as follows I believe:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 500);
});
```

The way you are doing it, the function scrollToBottom will be executed as soon as that code gets evaluated.

Comment: Ah! This was exactly the problem. It works now. Still don't entirely understand the difference between passing the function name with vs without the parenthesis, though.

Comment: With parenthesis, you are telling js to execute the function right away, without it, it's just a reference to the function in order to pass it as a callback and execute it after.

Comment: @taxicala Ah, I understand, thanks. Thanks for spotting this. I never would have found it otherwise.